# NSString.length gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring

I have the following code:

```
NSArray *array = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:nil];

NSString *temp;
for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++)
{
    temp = [array objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"temp length = %@", [temp length]);
}
```

I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error at the NSLog line. I assume it's erring out at the [temp length] bit. The weird thing is, I can do other methods of NSString on temp and they work fine, like `[temp characterAtIndex:0]`.

I've also tried doing `[[array objectAtIndex:i] retain];`, but that doesn't seem to help.

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error?

---

EDIT: Turns out it was crashing at the NSLog because it was %@ instead of %lu. The real problem was with other code that I had omitted from this post. After playing around with it some more, I got it working.

Comment: I suggest that you mark an answer as correct, considering that they did answer your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From my understanding, the "%@" placeholder is for object pointers, "length" returns "NSUInteger" which is not a pointer. Try "%lu" instead of "%@".

Comment: That didn't fix it... But interestingly enough, it made the error occur where the function call is, not actually on the line itself. Xcode also suggested %lu instead of %d, but both did the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

This (slightly cleaned up) version works for me:

```
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *path = [@"~/Desktop" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
    NSArray *array = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:
        path error:&error];
    if (error) NSLog(@"%@", error);

    for (NSString *path in array) {
        NSLog(@"Path length = %lu", path.length);
    }
```

As thg435 mentioned, "%@" is for object pointers, so if you pass it an arbitrary number it will throw a memory access error.